# Проксирование на nginx

Tags: nginx, проксирование

Задача такая:
Есть сервер, на котором лежат картинки.
Эти картинки проксируются на основной сайт.
Можно ли как-то в проксирование добавить метод, который будет отсеивать адреса 404?

Пробовали это:

```
if (!-f $request_filename ) {
   rewrite ^(.*[^/]).jpg$ /img/not_available.png redirect;
}
```

Пробовали такой вариант:

```
location ~ /upload/thumb/images/* {
 proxy_pass site.ru; 
 proxy_redirect     off;
 proxy_set_header   Host  "site.ru"; 
 proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_intercept_errors on;
 error_page 404 = @img404; 
 }
 location @img404 {
        try_files $uri /img/not_available.png;
 }
```

Но он не работает.

Можно ли как-то оживить второй вариант?
Необходимо, чтобы наш сервер обрабатывал 404 удаленного сервера таким образом, чтобы был редирект на /img/not_available.png нашего сервера

Comment: Что-то я не понял смысл вопроса. Что значит «отсеять»?

Comment: Напишите это в вопросе. А лучше весь конфиг

Comment: ИМХО при проксировании вы уже не обрабатываете 404 на первом nginx

Comment: вместо ```try_files $uri /img/not_available.png``` попробуйте использовать ```return 301 $scheme:://$host/img/not_available.png```

Comment: Увы, не сработало